Comparing values with surds (eg, $4\sqrt3 +1$ and $3\sqrt7$)
This question may be a bit too basic for some. I am working my way through a maths textbook. The question is:

Put the following numbers in ascending order:
$$7-4\sqrt3, \quad 8-3\sqrt{7}, \quad 9-4\sqrt5, \quad 10-3\sqrt{11}$$

I can just calculate it, but that is clearly not the point (I hope!). I can also see the pattern: incrementing integer, incrementing prime, alternating coefficient.
But I cannot see how to establish an inequality without in some way calculating the value. For example, is $4\sqrt3 +1$ greater than or less than $3\sqrt7$?

Looking at the differences between the numbers is a good idea, but I think these particular numbers have been chosen to make the ratios easier to look at. As a hint, note that $(3\sqrt{11})^2=99$ which is one less than $10^2$.

That's a helpful hint, but I am not sure what the proof of the sequence would be.

The rest have a similar form.  You need to decide whether this form is increasing or decreasing as the numbers in it get larger

You can use the following property of positive numbers:  If $a < b$, then $a^2 < b^2$.
Why is this true?
Let $0 < a < b$.  Then $b - a > 0$ by definition of $<$. Moreover, $b + a > 0$ since the sum of two positive numbers is positive.  Therefore,
$$b^2 - a^2 = (b + a)(b - a) > 0$$
because the product of two positive numbers is positive.
You considered the inequality
$$7 - 4\sqrt{3} \leq 8 - 3\sqrt{7}$$
If we add $-7 + 4\sqrt{3} + 3\sqrt{7}$ to both sides of the inequality, we obtain
$$3\sqrt{7} \leq 1 + 4\sqrt{3}$$
Since both sides are positive, the direction of the inequality is preserved if we square both sides of the inequality, which yields
\begin{align*}
63 & \leq 1 + 8\sqrt{3} + 48\\
14 & \leq 8\sqrt{3}
\end{align*}
Again, both sides of the inequality are positive, so we can square both sides of the inequality to obtain
$$196 \leq 192$$
which is a false statement.  Since the steps are reversible, we conclude that the inequality $7 - 4\sqrt{3} \leq 8 - 3\sqrt{7}$ must also have been false.  Hence,
$$7 - 4\sqrt{3} > 8 - 3\sqrt{7}$$

Thanks, that's excellent. I had the squaring but not the contradiction.

Having demonstrated that the first expression is larger than the second, does the pattern give a shortcut to the rest of the sequence?

My suspicion is that the sequence is strictly decreasing because the square root function grows more slowly as $x$ increases.  If I am right, you should be able to show that $8 - 3\sqrt{7} > 9 - 4\sqrt{5}$ by using a similar argument to the one I used above, although you don't need to argue by contradiction.

You can rewrite the sequence as $\sqrt{49}-\sqrt{48}$, $\sqrt{64}-\sqrt{63}$, $\sqrt{81}-\sqrt{80}$, $\sqrt{100}-\sqrt{99}$, which makes it easy to argue that the sequence is decreasing because the $\sqrt{\ }$ function grows ever more slowly.

Thanks, I am just trying to work out the logic that, if $(a-b)^2 > (c-d)^2$, then $a^2-b^2 > c^2-d^2$.

Using @JaapScherphuis's observation that the terms of the sequence have the form $n - \sqrt{n^2 - 1}$ (starting at $n = 7$), you can rationalize the numerator to obtain $$(n - \sqrt{n^2 - 1}) \cdot \frac{n + \sqrt{n^2 - 1}}{n + \sqrt{n^2 + 1}} = \frac{1}{n + \sqrt{n^2 + 1}}$$ which decreases as $n$ increases.

This is very helpful. Can you explain why rationalising the numerator shows the decrease, where the unrationalised expression does not? Is it just easier to see?

It is easier to see with the rationalized form since the fraction decreases as $n$ increases.
